# Active Directory distribution list inaccessible to external e-mail accounts

Tags: active-directory, g-suite, distribution-lists

I have created distribution lists for my organization. The members of these e-mail lists will not receive e-mails if the sender is e-mailing the list from an external e-mail.

Is there a way to allow internal distribution lists to receive e-mails from external senders?

I am using Google Apps as my mail server.

Answer (score 3):

This is controlled through the Google Apps Admin Console.

Go to Admin Console -> Users -> Group (DL) -> Roles and Permissions -> Who can send an e-mail to this group -> and select `anyone on the internet`.